# Iterate through numbers with specific condition

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to iterate through numbers which met a specific condition. I have done it with the following code. But it has two `for` loops which may not be efficient. Is it possible to make this code shorter?

```
for g in [i for i in range(10) if i % 2 == 0]:
    print(g)
```

I tried the following but this syntax does not work:

```
for i in range(10) if i % 2 == 0:
    print(i)
```

Comment: I don't understand why you don't just add an `if` in the loop to check the condition. Can't you just do `for ...:\n if...:\n print i`?

Comment: in this specific case, `for i in range(0, 10, 2):` is an option

Answer (score 2):

The second syntax is invalid, but you can split it into two lines:

```
for i in range(10):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

If shortening your code is the motive(which shouldn't be), then here are 2 one-liners:

```
>>> print('\n'.join(map(str, filter(lambda x:not x%2, range(10)))))
0
2
4
6
8
```

or

```
>>> print('\n'.join(map(str, range(0, 10, 2))))
0
2
4
6
8
```